# Formview Image Control clears imageURL set by code upon mode switch

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an `asp:Formview` which contains an `asp:Image` that has its `ImageURL` set to a separate `DataBound` value on page load using some C# code, but when the Formview mode is switched to edit - the imageURL value is lost, even though I set it again in an OnModeChanged method.
The code looks like:
**aspx**

```
<asp:FormView ID="accountFormview" runat="server" DefaultMode="ReadOnly" OnModeChanged="accountFormview_ModeChanged" DataSourceID="UserDataSource" DataKeyNames="User_Id" style="margin-right: 1px; float:left;" Width="512px">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="imgAvatar" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/defaultAccountImage.png" Height="100px" BorderColor="#003399" BorderWidth="1px" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAvatarFilePath" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Avatar_Img_Path") %>'> 
    </asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
  
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="imgAvatar" runat="server" Height="100px" BorderColor="#003399" BorderWidth="1px"/>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAvatarFilePath" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Avatar_Img_Path") %>'> 
    </asp:TextBox>>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

**C#**

```
string avatarFileName = ((TextBox)accountFormview.FindControl("txtAvatarFilePath")).Text;
Image avatarImage = avatarImage = (Image)accountFormview.FindControl("imgAvatar");
string saveFilePath = @"\\" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FileServer"].ToString() + @"\Images\"
if( File.Exists(saveFilePath + "\\" + avatarFileName))
{
    avatarImage.ImageUrl = saveFilePath + "\\" + avatarFileName;
}
else
{
    avatarImage.ImageUrl = @"~\Images\defaultAccountImage.png";
}
```

Example:
Page Loaded - dog images appear
Select edit - gone
Cancel back to ReadOnly - gone again
[image: error example]

I can't databind the ImageURL by default since it needs to use the ConfigurationManager. The C# code is called on the PageLoad and sets the images just fine - but once the mode of the Formview is changed - they are set to default even when I have the OnModeChanged method also call the C# code.

Answer (score 0):

Found a fix for this by adding changing the `asp:FormView` to use `OnPreRender` instead of `OnModeChanged` to call displaying the images. So the fixed code looks like:

```
<asp:FormView ID="accountFormview" runat="server" DefaultMode="ReadOnly"  
 OnPreRender="accountFormview_ModeChanged" 
 DataSourceID="UserDataSource" DataKeyNames="User_Id" style="margin-right: 1px; float:left;" Width="512px">
```